# Can someone help me with TrustZone project?

Tags: c++, cpu-architecture

http://tristartom.github.io/teaching/15f-cis655/projs/trustzone/

So basically I have to do this project where I have to simulate the working of ARM trustzone technology using C++. The link is mentioned above.

I have to show the switching between two types of world - 'normal world ' and 'secure world'by using a smc() call - [link] http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0098a/armccref_ch04s01s13.htm

I am not able to understand how to simulate or show this operation using Visual studio.

It would be of great help if someone helped me understand what I need to do.